# Hide zero integers in axis with numbers smaller than one in ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

If there are only numbers smaller than one displayed in an axis, is there a way using ggplot (or any other R functions) to not display the zero integer? For example, on my x-axis are displayed numbers ranging from 0.25 to 0.65, by 0.05. Instead of displaying: 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 … I was wondering if there is some way to display these numbers without the zero integer, like this: .25 .30 .35 .40 and so on.

These are some example codes of a plot with an x-axis with only numbers smaller than one (I just wish not to display the zero integer):

```
mydata = data.frame(q = seq(.25, .65, by=.05), response = rnorm(9))
ggplot(mydata, aes(y=response,x=q)) +
geom_line(aes(y=response))  +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(.25, .65, .05))
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
mydata = data.frame(q = seq(.25, .65, by=.05), response = rnorm(9))
ggplot(mydata, aes(y=response,x=q)) +
geom_line(aes(y=response))  +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(.25, .65, .05), labels=sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", seq(.25, .65, .05))))
```

[image]